# How to use Emacs in Clions External Tools

Tags: c++, emacs, clion

I am trying to use the external tools function in Clion to be able to use Emacs to edit source files. Ive tried following some tutorials telling how to open files in emacs through IntelliJ, but didnt get the same results with Clion, or Rider for that matter. Whats the correct way of doing this without just manually opening the files in emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think perhaps this [post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/07/intellij-emacs/)

could help :)